# In R, How to use regular expression to split string?

Tags: regex, r

Assume i have a text with format like this (four spaces are one tab):

```
__spiritual_bouquet_1    _type_of    __sympathy_card_1
```

And i want to split it by tab to:

`__spiritual_bouquet_1`, `_type_of`, `__sympathy_card_1`

I don't know how use regular expression to split it.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I disagree with that edit, there where actual tabs in the [raw source](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/416f6319-546b-48ef-a034-5aff0c2e4041/view-source) of the post not correctly rendered by SO markdown (and the "4 spaces = 1 tab" part doesn't makes any sense now). user3758586, can you break the tie and improve your question's formatting?

Comment: @Robin, maybe you right, I didn't look in the raw source, I rolled it back

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
strsplit(subject, "\\s", perl=TRUE);
```

**Explanation**

`\s` matches a white-space character, which means spaces, tabs and carriage returns. I didn't use the tab character `\t` because in the sample string I only found a regular space character.

**Option 2: Getting Rid of the Extra Underscore**

I notice that some of your tokens have double underscores near the delimiter. If you want to remove the extra underscore, you can use this regex: `\s(?:_(?=_))?`

In R: `strsplit(subject, "\\s(?:_(?=_))?", perl=TRUE);`

On [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/kJ1tD1), you can see how we only match an underscore where it is doubled. We split on this delimiter.

**How this one works:**

- `\\s` matches a whitespace character
- `(?:_(?=_))?` is a non-capturing group, made optional by the `?` at the end, that matches an underscore, but only as the lookahead `(?=_)` is able to assert that the following character is an underscore

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: I don't think that your "getting rid of the extra underscore" code works as expected...

Comment: @DavidArenburg Ha, why not? Did you see [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/hN6uK1)? If there's a bug, please let me know. :) Thanks!

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yeah, people tend to dislike these empty first matches... Took it out, so we're only targetting underscores in the middle. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
temp <- "__spiritual_bouquet_1    _type_of    __sympathy_card_1"
strsplit(temp, " ")[[1]]
```

This will give you some extra empty results. So alternativly you could do

```
strsplit(temp, " ")[[1]][strsplit(temp, " ")[[1]] != ""]
```